# flutter : Error (Xcode): building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS for "record_mp3-3.0.0" architecture arm64

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, simulator

I am using the record_mp3-3.0.0 package

[image]

`Error (Xcode): In /Users/mohamedwazery/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/record_mp3-3.0.0/ios/Classes/Fat-Lame/lib/libmp3lame.a(VbrTag.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/mohamedwazery/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/record_mp3-3.0.0/ios/Classes/Fat-Lame/lib/libmp3lame.a' for architecture arm64`

`Could not build the application for the simulator.`
`Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.`

I added "arm64" in the Excluded architecture in xcode,
But I get the same error

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, but if run in device it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by updating `Podfile` with this:

```
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  
  config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
end
```

Don't forget to `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`